# Table spacing and alignment

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm having some problems with tables:

1) Right now cells are centrally aligned (horizontal & vertical). I would like to centre the cells horizontally only so that the text remains at the top of the cell.

2) The line spacing between different cells is perfect. However inside the cell i want the line spacing to be less so i can differentiate between different cells and multi-line cells. (See 3rd row)

Thanks for the help

Here's my code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{array}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
        \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \hline
        Parameter                                                                   
        & MSF                                                                                   
        & MED                                                                          
        & RO                                                                                
        & ED         \\ \hline

        Application
        & SW/BW 1
        & SW/BW
        & SW/BW     
        & BW        \\                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Market share2 (\%)\end{tabular}
        & 27 
        & 8
        & 4
        & 60         \\

        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Water production\\cost  (\$/m\textsuperscript{3})\end{tabular}    
        & 0.56--1.75
        & 0.52--1.5  
        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}0.45--1.72 (SW)\\   0.26--1.33 (BW)\end{tabular}  
        & 0.6--1.05 \\                                                                                                                                               

        \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

     \end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: tabular are vertically centred by default you can top-align them using the optional argument but you used `\begin{tabular}[c]` that should be `[t]`

Comment: Please always post a complete document so people can test answers

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks that solved the first problem. And i completed the code

Comment: presumably you want `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}` before your inner tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
   \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
   \hline
   Parameter
   & MSF
   & MED
   & RO
   & ED         \\ \hline

   Application
   & SW/BW 1
   & SW/BW
   & SW/BW
   & BW        \\

   Market share2 (\%)
   & 27
   & 8
   & 4
   & 60         \\

   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Water production\\[-10pt] cost (\$/m\textsuperscript{3})\end{tabular}
   & 0.56--1.75
   & 0.52--1.5
   & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}0.45--1.72 (SW)\\[-10pt] 0.26--1.33 (BW)\end{tabular}
   & 0.6--1.05 \\  \hline

   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

or (easier)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
   \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
   \hline
   Parameter
   & MSF
   & MED
   & RO
   & ED         \\ \hline

   Application
   & SW/BW 1
   & SW/BW
   & SW/BW
   & BW        \\

   Market share2 (\%)
   & 27
   & 8
   & 4
   & 60         \\

   Water production
   & 0.56--1.75
   & 0.52--1.5
   & 0.45--1.72 (SW)
   & 0.6--1.05 \\[-10pt]

   cost (\$/m\textsuperscript{3})
   &
   &
   & 0.26--1.33 (BW)
   &          \\

   \hline

   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without changing `\arraystretch`. It uses `makecell` and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadalign{tc}
\renewcommand\cellalign{tl}
\setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
   \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
   \toprule
   Parameter
   & MSF
   & MED
   & RO
   & ED \\
   \midrule
   Application
   & SW/BW 1
   & SW/BW
   & SW/BW
   & BW \\
%
   Market share2 (\%)
   & 27
   & 8
   & 4
   & 60 \\
%
  \makecell{Water production\\cost (\$/m\textsuperscript{3})}
   & 0.56--1.75
   & 0.52--1.5
   & \thead{0.45--1.72 (SW)\\0.26--1.33 (BW)}
   & 0.6--1.05 \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]